# Deny access in Symfony method unless you are in localhost

Tags: php, symfony, security, localhost

I want to know **how to deny the access** to a controller method **that it isn't being called from localhost**. For example, I would like to allow the access to this URL `www.myweb.com/usermanagement` only if you are on localhost.

I didn't find anything on doc https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/security.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the solution of fxbt is great.

But you can also do it by using the firewall configuration in security.yaml file: https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/security/firewall_restriction.html

```
# app/config/security.yml

# ...
security:
    firewalls:
        # This is a custom firewall area and may conflict with your existing firewall
        other_secured_area:
            host: ^localhost$
            pattern: ^/usermanagement
```

Another solution is to do it directly in the controller:

```php
public function userManagement(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->getHost() !== 'localhost') {
        throw new $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
}
```

In any case by careful because host security may not be the best security (it's possible to manipulate the host from the client in most cases).

Answer (score 3):

Look in the [access_control documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression). You can use the `allow_if` key and do something like this:

```
access_control:
    - path: ^/usermanagement
      allow_if: "request.getHost() == 'localhost'"
```